# Update Specific Pandas Rows with Value from Different Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains budget data but my sales data is located in another dataframe that is not the same size.  How can I get my sales data updated in my budget data? How can I write conditions so that it makes these updates?

```
DF budget:
        cust   type   loc   rev   sales   spend
    0   abc    new    north 500   0       250
    1   def    new    south 700   0       150
    2   hij    old    south 700   0       150

DF sales:
        cust    type   loc    sales
    0   abc     new    north  15
    1   hij     old    south  18

DF budget outcome:
        cust   type   loc   rev   sales   spend
    0   abc    new    north 500   15      250
    1   def    new    south 700   0       150
    2   hij    old    south 700   18      150
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at pandas merge()

Comment: Extending on @Bob Haffner suggestion, there is also join http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html

Comment: hm, i've looked at using pd.merge(...) however it merges all the columns.  I'm only looking to update a specif column/series within the dataframe. in this case, it's only 'sales'.

Comment: @gall3on then just use access those specific columns (e.g. pd.merge(df1[['col1','col2']],df2,left_on......)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that 'cust' column is unique in your other df, you can call `map` on the sales df after setting the index to be the 'cust' column, this will map for each 'cust' in budget df to it's sales value, additionally you will get `NaN` where there are missing values so you call `fillna(0)` to fill those values:

```
In [76]:

df['sales'] = df['cust'].map(df1.set_index('cust')['sales']).fillna(0)
df
Out[76]:
  cust type    loc  rev  sales  spend
0  abc  new  north  500     15    250
1  def  new  south  700      0    150
2  hij  old  south  700     18    150
```